# Redshift SQL REGEXP_REPLACE function

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a value which is duplicated from source (can't do anything about that). I have read some examples here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html

Example value:
ABC$ABC$
So just trimming anything after the first '€'. I tried this, but I cannot figure out the correct REGEX expression.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '€.*\\.$', '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex pattern is including a dot as the final character.  Remove it and your approach should work:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '€.*$', '') AS value_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

> So just trimming anything after the first '€'.

Why use regex at all? Why not just..

```
SELECT LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('€', value)-1)
```

If not all your data has a euro sign, consider `WHERE value like '%€%'`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can take the initial sequence of non-€ characters:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^[^€]+')
```